# Raise an event whenever a property value gets changed

Tags: objective-c

I have a class having 2 properties:

```
@property (copy) NSString *name; //name of the file
@property (copy) NSString *path; //path of the file
@property NSImage *img; //icon of the file
```

**Problem**
I want to name and img auto fill whenever path is changed like an event should be raised whenever the path is changed so that I can refresh name and img.

Many thanks in advance. Please note that I am 2 months new to objective-c and I was in the .net world from the last 2 years.

Comment: Create `readonly` properties for `name` and `img`.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Then the variables can't be changed at all. It's like the `final` keyword in Java.

Comment: Actually, the question is how can I monitor if path is getting changed. I want to know if the path is changed so that I can change the name and img accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated to prevent looping)*
You could use a setter function. Instead of using `MyClass.name = ...` declare a function in that class and use that to change the value:

```
- (void) setPath:(NSString*)newvalue{
    _path = newvalue;
    [self updateNameAndPicture];
}
```

Then, when you change it, use

```
[InstanceOfMyClass setPath:@"/new/path/"];
```

Comment: I have just tried your answer, but the event is not getting raised. Actually, this class is already been used widely in the project and now we have added 2 more fields in the model class and now we have to fill these two fields whenever the "path" is getting changed.

Comment: By "event" do you mean `NSEvent`?

Comment: **Caution:** This syntax will probably cause in infinite loop, because `self.path` will call the setter again and again. Use the backed index variable to store the value `_path = newvalue;`

Comment: @Arc676 actually, I just took reference of a event. By event, I just meant that I need something that let me know whenever the value is changed.

Comment: It worked thanks :). As Vadian said it was causing infinite loop thats why my app was not working but now it is good going. Thanks vadian and arc676

Answer (score 3):

You can go with a well established **KVO (Key-Value Observing) technique**:

**Step 1 :** Assuming you already have a model class say `MyData` with these properties, set your controller class or where you are creating that model object as observer for `path` something like this:

```
MyData *data = [[MyData alloc] init];
[data addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"path" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

**Step 2 :** Implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method to listen to any change in the `path` property. Something like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    MyData *myData = (MyData *)object;
    myData.name = @"My Name";
    myData.image = // Set your image here
}
```

**Step 3 :** Importantly, do not forget to remove yourself as observer of this property whenever your object is being deallocated. Otherwise you may end up crashing!

Comment: You might want to add that this technique is called KVO and is an important, established part of Cocoa.

Comment: KVO is an important technique, though "Step 3," needing to remove the observer is a longstanding annoyance.  You'd think they could just add some glue to `dealloc`... if ARC works...